# Can you do a phd in maths at Cambridge university without an honours degree?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I graduated from an australian university last year with a bachelor of mechanical engineering with first class honors and a bachelor of mathematics. If I want to get an honours degree in maths, I need to study for an additional year.

I wish to apply for phd admission in pure maths at Cambridge university. The admission webpage says that the minimum requirement is a first class honours in mathematics or a related area. Am I eligible or I have to study an extra year to get my honours in maths first and then apply to Cambridge? I am interested in analytic number theory if it makes any difference.

Note: I emailed my question to people at Cambridge university but I have not received any replies after a week.

Comment: I would wait a while longer to hear back from the Graduate Admissions Office, they are typically very busy around this time of the year.

Comment: You might need an equivalent of a masters however. As far as I know, it is expected of European students to have a masters before starting the PhD.

Comment: Have you considered doing [Part III](https://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/part-iii-prospective) before the PhD? I gather that particular course lends itself well to those wanting to do a maths PhD at Cambridge.

Comment: The answer to this question is "You can if and only if Cambridge says you can."  So you *have* to ask them.  I've voted to close.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of an honour student, honour course, etc. might differ between universities, some universities don't have this concept at all. So your degree from your home university might be enough for Cambridge or not, maybe even a honours degree from your university might not be enough.

Who did you email at Cambridge? You might want to try to contact something like an international office, they might be able to tell you the exact requirements for an international student applying.